# How do I control vertical line spacing under \settabs in plain TeX?

Tags: spacing, plain-tex

Consider the following example.

```
\settabs \+ \hskip 4.5 in & \cr
\+ Silahkan masuk & Come in, please! \cr
\+ Silahkan duduk & Sit down, please! \cr
\+ Silahkan berdiri & Stand up, please! \cr
\bye
```

#### How can I increase the vertical space between each line?

Note that this question is about *TeX* and **not** *LaTeX*.

I have tried `\parskip` but it had no effect in this situation.

Comment: Do you mean for all lines or on a line-by-line basis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to open up the space of the whole table, then use the `\openup` macro before the tabs:

```
\begingroup\openup 6pt
\settabs \+ \hskip 4.5 in & \cr
\+ Silahkan masuk & Come in, please! \cr
\+ Silahkan duduk & Sit down, please! \cr
\+ Silahkan berdiri & Stand up, please! \cr
\endgroup
```

You probably want to isolate this change inside a group, so I've shown it inside a `begingroup` and `endgroup` pair.

If you just want space after a particular line, just add a suitable skip command.

```
\settabs \+ \hskip 4.5 in & \cr
\+ Silahkan masuk & Come in, please! \cr
\medskip
\+ Silahkan duduk & Sit down, please! \cr
\+ Silahkan berdiri & Stand up, please! \cr
```

Answer (score 2):

A `\+` line is implemented as a one line `\halign`, but called via `\ialign` that clears `\everycr`. One might define a different version of `\ialign` that doesn't perform that step and add `\everycr{\noalign{\vskip2pt}}` or any desired length, with the effect that such a skip will be inserted *twice*, so a double `\vskip` is needed at the top to balance the one at the bottom.

If no vertical spacing around the table is desired, the double *negative* `\vskip` can be added at the end.

```
\catcode`@=11
\def\ialignx{\tabskip\z@skip\halign} % initialized \halign
\catcode`@=12

\input plipsum

\lipsum{2}

\begingroup
\par\vskip4pt\relax % compensate the bottom spacing
\let\ialign\ialignx % use locally \ialignx
\everycr{\noalign{\vskip2pt}}
\settabs \+ \hskip 2in & \cr
\+ Silahkan masuk & Come in, please! \cr
\+ Silahkan duduk & Sit down, please! \cr
\+ Silahkan berdiri & Stand up, please! \cr
\endgroup

\lipsum{3}

\begingroup
\let\ialign\ialignx % use locally \ialignx
\everycr{\noalign{\vskip2pt}}
\settabs \+ \hskip 2in & \cr
\+ Silahkan masuk & Come in, please! \cr
\+ Silahkan duduk & Sit down, please! \cr
\+ Silahkan berdiri & Stand up, please! \cr
\vskip-4pt\relax % compensate the top non spacing
\endgroup

\lipsum{4}

\bye
```

[image]

I'd recommend adding vertical spacing around such constructions anyway: the second example shows why.